# How to transform coordinates from heliocentric to a view from earth?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, reference-frames, orbital-motion, coordinate-systems, celestial-mechanics

I'm trying to find and model the apparent motion of the retrograde motion of Mars as viewed on Earth, incorporating Lagrangian or Hamiltonian mechanics.

For the lagrangian I have:

$L = \frac{1}{2}m_{Earth}(\dot{r}_{Earth}^2 + r_{Earth}^2 \dot{\theta}_{Earth}^2) + \frac{1}{2}m_{Mars}(\dot{r}_{Mars}^2 + r_{Mars}^2 \dot{\theta}_{Mars}^2) + \frac{G M_{Sun} M_{Earth}}{r_{Earth}} + \frac{G M_{Sun} M_{Mars}}{r_{Mars}}$

My question is, this gives the orbits of Earth and mars with respect to the Sun. How can I transform these coordinates to a view of Mars from Earth?

Comment: Your Lagrangian doesn't make much sense. You can't just use $r$ and $\theta$.
Instead, you need to use $r_{\text{Earth}}$, $r_{\text{Mars}}$,
$\theta_{\text{Earth}}$ and $\theta_{\text{Mars}}$.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware, just makes it a bit more cluttered. Was hoping people would be able to tell. Guess I'll edit it.

Comment: You solve the equations, find the orbits, and then subtract the position of Mars from that of the Earth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no easy trick
to directly get the geocentric coordinates of Mars by Lagrangian or Hamiltonian dynamics.
But you can calculate these relative coordinates by a simple vector subtraction:

[image]

$$\vec{r}_\text{relative}=\vec{r}_\text{Mars}-\vec{r}_\text{Earth}$$

or written in cartesian coordinates
$$\begin{align}
x_\text{relative}&=x_\text{Mars}-x_\text{Earth} \\
y_\text{relative}&=y_\text{Mars}-y_\text{Earth}
\end{align}$$

And converting cartesian to polar coordinates you get
$$\begin{align}
r_\text{relative}\cos\theta_\text{relative}&=
r_\text{Mars}\cos\theta_\text{Mars}-
r_\text{Earth}\cos\theta_\text{Earth} \\
r_\text{relative}\sin\theta_\text{relative}&=
r_\text{Mars}\sin\theta_\text{Mars}-
r_\text{Earth}\sin\theta_\text{Earth}
\end{align}$$

Then you need to solve these two equations for
$r_\text{relative}$ and $\theta_\text{relative}$.

Comment: And that can take the place of the r and theta in the lagrangian?

Comment: Or do you apply that after you get the EoM?

Comment: @Cobra04 You do that after you solved the EoM.

Comment: Ok, Thank you I appreciate it!